# Run .sql file in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Are there any way to run .sql file on hard disk except using sqlcmd or osql.

Comment: why you need do that? more info pls

Comment: I couldn't get result I want.

Answer (score 1):

Other than `SQLCMD` or `OSQL`; you can use `SSMS` if you have it installed. Double click on the `*.sql` file and it will open in SSMS -> connect to the DB server instance -> click on run in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is the wrong tool to run 'files'. Is not an automation tool. Use sqlcmd or PowerShell for automation.

Now strict to your question: SSMS can run queries in [SQLCMD mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa833281%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), in which the `:r` command is available:

> `:r FileName`
>   Parses additional Transact-SQL statements and SQLCMD commands from the file specified by FileName into the statement cache. FileName is read relative to the startup directory for Visual Studio. The file is read and executed after a batch terminator is encountered. You can issue multiple :r commands. The file can include any SQLCMD command, including the batch terminator that is defined in Tools, Options. You can use :r in a pre-deployment or post-deployment script to include other scripts.

Comment: I did not mean SSMS. SSMS is the easiest way. I want to run with a script like EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -S BORA -d master -i D:\test.sql', but this command made a fuss. Instead sqlcmd, I am trying to find anohter way.

Comment: Don't run remote sql from inside a script, with xp_cmdshell. Is not sqlcmd making a 'fuss', is constrained delegation and **all** tools will make the same fuss.

Comment: how can i run remote sql without using xp_cmdshell. You say that run it from command line?